# AngularJS JSON getting all the time on details page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, get, xmlhttprequest

Long story short, i've got a 2 page angular js app(the reason is becuase i'm integrating it into CMS templates and a single page app wouldn't work too well with the CMS widgets in the sidebar).

Anyway...I have a big results page that pulls in 3 different JSON files using AngularJS 1.5.x factory and $q services. This is all controlled by a controller called **EventsListCtrl**.

When you click on an item it then takes you to the details page which is another single page app using angular(as mentioned in intro). The details page picks up x variables in the url and then goes through the correct JSON file to pull out the correct record. This is controlled by a separate controller called **EventDetailCtrl**.

So it only gets 1 JSON depending what's in the URL but i've noticed in the log it's still pulling all three JSON files. How can I get it to stop pulling all three JSON files.

The aim is to just reduce page load speeds and stop pulling in JSON files I don't need.

An example of my detailed controller can be seen below:

```
// Event Detail Page
    function eventDetailCtrl(MyService, $filter){
        var vm = this;

        vm.eventStatus = 'Loading';
        vm.eventId = window.location.toString().split('?id=')[1].split('&ref')[0];
        vm.noResults = '<h4>Sorry, something went wrong.</h4>The page you requested could not be found.';

        activateEventDetail();

        function activateEventDetail(){
            MyService.getEventData.then(
                function(response){
                    vm.eventResults = response;
                    vm.eventId = $filter('filter')(vm.eventResults,{Id: vm.eventId})[0];
                    vm.eventStatus = 'Success';
                    if(vm.eventId != undefined){
                       window.document.title = "Network West Midlands - Event: " + vm.eventId.Title;
                    }else{
                        vm.eventStatus = 'Error';
                        window.document.title = "Network West Midlands - Event: " + 'Sorry';
                    }
                },function(error){
                    vm.eventStatus = 'Error';
                    console.log('EventDetail Error: ' + error.statusText);
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

The MyService is my factory which uses the standard promises technique as seen below:

```
.factory('MyService',['$http','$q', myService]);

    function myService($http, $q){
        var eventfulData = $http.get('FutureEvents', {cache: 'true'});
        var googleData = $http.get('WmPlacesList', {cache: 'true'});
        var facebookEvents = $http.get('FacebookNwm', {cache: 'true'});

        return {
            getEventData: getData(eventfulData),
            getAttractionData: getData(googleData),
            getfbEvents: getData(facebookEvents)
        }

        function getData(jsonData){
            /* Just a generic deferred object that we will resolve manually. */
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $q.when($q.all([jsonData])).then(getDataComplete,getDataFail);

            return defer.promise;

            function getDataComplete(response){
                var finalData = response[0].data;
                defer.resolve(finalData);
            }

            function getDataFail(response){
                defer.reject(response);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues

```
   return {
        getEventData: getData(eventfulData),// invokes getData()
        getAttractionData: getData(googleData),
        getfbEvents: getData(facebookEvents)
    }
```

This is invoking `getData` not passing as reference. That is why you are getting 3 requests made.

You could write it as

```
return {
  getEventData: function() {
    return getData(eventfulData);
  },
  getAttractionData: function() {
    return getData(googleData);
  },
  getfbEvents: function() {
    return getData(facebookEvents);
  }
}
```

There is no need to use `$q` in `getData()` since `$http` already returns a promise. It can be streamined into something like:

```
function getData(jsonData) {
  return jsonData.then(getDataComplete)
                 .catch(getDataFail);    
}

function getDataComplete(response) {
  return response.data;
}

function getDataFail(response) {
  // not sure what you want to do for errors
}
```

Now in controller you need to invoke `MyService.getEventData`

So change :

```
MyService.getEventData.then(
```

To

```
MyService.getEventData().then(
```

Comment: I've marked this as the correct answer as it helped shorten my code and lead me on the right path. The only thing that was missing was to include my var(s) within the return functions e.g.

`getfbEvents: function() {

                var facebookEvents = $http.get('FacebookNwm', {cache: 'true'});

                return getData(facebookEvents);
              }`